# How to define the smallest difference between two arrays?

Tags: c#

So there are two columns of data in a text file, numbers only.
I have to write out the smallest difference from the whole file that these two columns have.

For example 150;200 | 175;200 | 300;310 | 100;500 and I have to get an answer like 10 because that is the smallest difference between those two numbers.

I tried to do it with Math.Abs but I don't really know how to get the smallest amount from it

[This is the text file that I'm talking about, ignore the year numbers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOW10.png)
    namespace Uzemanyag
{
    struct uzi
    {
        public DateTime datum; //The dates but just ignore them
        public int benzin; //the numbers from the second column
        public int gazolaj; //numbers from the third

```
}
class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] g = File.ReadAllLines("uzemanyag.txt");

        int h = g.Length;
        List<uzi> u = new List<uzi>(h);

        for (int i = 0; i < h ; i++)
        {
            string[] f = g[i].Split(';'); //made them split into different datas at ;
            uzi w = new uzi(); 

            w.datum = Convert.ToDateTime(f[0]);
            w.benzin = Convert.ToInt32(f[1]);
            w.gazolaj = Convert.ToInt32(f[2]);

            u.Add(w);

        }

        int kul = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < g.Length; i++)
        {
            kul = Math.Abs(u[i].benzin - u[i].gazolaj);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(kul);

struct uzi
{
    public DateTime datum; //The dates but just ignore them
    public int benzin; //the numbers from the second column
    public int gazolaj; //numbers fromt the third

}
```

Comment: Okay.  Can you show us how you tried to implement this?  We can help you get it working.  If this is homework, you should make an attempt at it.  We would be happy to help you, but we're generally less keen on doing work *for* people, so we like to see some effort.

Comment: You say in your question that your file has two columns, but the data in the question is on one line separated by pipes.  Can you clarify the contents of your data file?

Comment: Calculate the difference for each pair/set and keep the smallest one you encounter?

Comment: Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp exactly

Comment: Kristjan Kica Hey, it's not my homework, I just trying to prepare myself for the final exam and this is a type that I don't know how to do..

Comment: @y_os Can you edit your question with the contents of the text file *as text*, not as an image?  That will make it easier for us to work with.  Why doesn't that screenshot show the same data that is already present?  It looks like each line is prefixed with a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer is good, and it is good practice to see how to do this directly. However it is worth pointing out that this sequence operation is a one-liner using LINQ. Instead of:

```
int kul = int.MaxValue;
for (int i = 0; i < g.Length; i++)
{
    int diff = Math.Abs(u[i].benzin - u[i].gazolaj);
    kul = Math.Min(kul, diff);
}
```

You can just write

```
int kul = u.Select(i => Math.Abs(i.benzin - i.gazolaj)).Min();
```

Learning what sequence operations are available in the standard library is a powerful way to improve your box of tools; I recommend that you look into it. For example, your comment on the accepted answer is:

> How can I count how many times did it occur?

That would be

```
var diffs = u.Select(i => Math.Abs(i.benzin - i.gazolaj));
int kul = diffs.Min();
int count = diffs.Count(i => i == kul);
```

All the basic operations you have to do on sequences -- count, join, group, filter, project, zip, and so on -- are built in to the standard library. You do not have to write the loops yourself!

Comment: Thank you! With this solution, it's pretty short and simple! But the first and last line of the code is a little bit foggy for me. Where could I learn about these?

Comment: @y_os: The phrases you want to search for are "LINQ" and "lambda expression".

Answer (score 3):

You're close.  You just need to get the smallest amount.

```
int kul = int.MaxValue;
for (int i = 0; i < g.Length; i++)
{
    int diff = Math.Abs(u[i].benzin - u[i].gazolaj);
    kul = Math.Min(kul, diff);
}
```

How this works:

Start out with a ridiculously large number.  Then on each iteration, we get the absolute difference between the two numbers, and keep whichever is smaller: `kul`, or the difference.  On the first iteration, because `kul` is a very large number, it will immediately become the difference of the first two numbers.  On later iterations, it will keep the smaller number.

If you start `kul` with zero, this won't work, as it's already the smallest non-negative integer.

Comment: Thank you it solved it! But I have another question to you. So here the smallest number is 0. How can I count how many times did it occur?

Comment: How many times what occurred?  For clarity, what is "it" referring to?

Comment: @y_os Also, can you share the `uzi` class?  To answer this new question, I think knowing how it is declared will become relevant.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear.  Could you add `uzi` to the question?  (Code in comments is hard to read.)

Comment: I mean the value of kul

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205778/discussion-between-amy-and-y-os).